# How many bit strings of length $20$ have either less than ten $1$’s or contain $11$ as a substring

Tags: combinatorics

How many bit strings of length $20$ have either less than ten $1$’s or contain $11$ as a substring? The answer is $2^{20}-2$.

I am wondering how did they get $2$? Because if a string contains $11$ as a substring, then out of $20$ positions $2$ of them are fixed. Furthermore if the string has more than ten ones in it, then the solution to get those ten positions specifically will be $_{20}C_{10}$. (Note I am not taking the substring case into consideration here as of now.)

Hence the number of strings will be $2^{20}-\ _{20}C_{12}$. But the answer is $2^{20}-2$. Can someone give me a better explanation? Or is my chain of reasoning wrong?

Comment: Here's a better question : except for $010101010101010101,101010101010101010$ every other bit string of length $20$ would have this property. Knowing this, can you see why the answer comes?

Comment: $2^{20}$ is the number of length-20 bitstrings.  In the case that there are strictly more than $10$ 1's then there are eleven or more $1$'s, i.e. nine or fewer $0$'s.  By pigeon-hole principle within the spaces to the left or right or inbetween each of those $0$'s (*there are at most ten such spaces*), there must be at least one space with two or more $1$'s in it (since $11>10$) which would cause a substring of $11$.  We see then that *every* string with strictly less than ten $1$'s and *every* string with strictly more than ten $1$'s will satisfy one of our conditions...

Comment: Hi Sparsh! Welcome to MSE! You will find that you will receive more, better answers if you take the time to format your questions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (much of the time you can just put your mathematical expressions in dollar signs (maybe with some curly braces): e.g. `2^20-2` could be written `$2^{20}-2$` to be written as $2^{20}-2$.

Comment: Notice you are taking the NEGATION of " less than ten 1’s" but you are taking the POSITIVE of " contain 11 as a substring".  Why are you doing that?  Either calculate 'less that ten 1's' + 'has 11 as substring - ('less than ten 1s and 11 as subtring') and take the POSITIVES of bot with exclusion inclusion or calculate $2^{20} - $ (more than ten 1's and no 11's) and take the NEGATIVE of both.  Hint:  (more than ten 1's and no 11's) = 2.  Just 2.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricksy question.

Let P mean "has $11$ as substring" and  Q mean "has less than 10 $1$s".

Then # of P or Q = #all - #NEITHER( P nor Q) = #all - #BOTH NOT P AND NOT Q.

#all =  $2^{20}$.

NOT P means "never has $11$ as a substring" means "every one has a $0$ to either side of it".

NOT Q means has at least $10$ $1$.

NOT P AND NOT Q means that at least $10$ $1$s and every one has a $0$ to either so so at least $10$ $0$ but as there are at most $20$ bits there are $10$ $0$s and $10$ $1$ and all the $1$ have a $0$ between them.

So NOT P AND NOT Q means "either $10101010101010101010$ or $01010101010101010101$.  So

# NOT P AND NOT Q = $2$.

So # of P or Q = #all - #NEITHER( P nor Q) = #all - #BOTH NOT P AND NOT Q = $2^{20} - 2$